# undefined is not a function-Node.JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback

could you please help me undesrtand the reason why I get "undefined if not a function" error message!:

Here is my code:

```
function write(dest, data, cb) {
            var safe_write = function (cb) {
                var tmpname = tempFile(dest)
                fs.writeFile(tmpname, data, function (err) {
                    if (err)
                        return cb(err)
                    renameTmp(tmpname, dest, cb)
                })
            }

            safe_write(function (err) {
                if (err && err.code === 'ENOENT') {
                    mkdirp(Path.dirname(dest), function (err) {
                        if (err)
                            return cb(err)
                        safe_write(cb)
                    })
                } else {
                    cb(err);// The error message is coming from here!
                }
            })
        }
```

I'm calling it in somewhere like this:

```
module.exports.write_json = function (name, value, cb) {
    var foo = nano.db.use('foo');
    value['_id'] = value['name'];
    foo.get(value['name'], function (err, body) {
        if (err && err.error == "not_found") {
            foo.insert(value, function (err, response) {
                write(name, JSON.stringify(value, null, '\t'), cb(err))
            })
        } else {
            var data = lodash.merge(body, value);
            foo.atomic("update", "inplace", value['name'], data, function (err, response) {
                write(name, JSON.stringify(data, null, '\t'), cb(err))
            })
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: That means that `cb` is `undefined`.

Comment: You mean where I'm calling it?

Comment: How are you calling `write()`? You might be missing an argument or said argument is undefined.

Comment: It means that the parameter `cb` has no value; how are you calling `write()`?

Comment: Thanks @Pointy and MinusFour ; I updated my code to see how I'm calling it; still I have no clue why I'm getting this error!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `write()`, you're passing `cb(err)`

```
write(name, JSON.stringify(data, null, '\t'), cb(err))
```

If `cb` is a function, then `cb(err)` **calls the function** and the return value is what's passed to `write()`. That's where your `undefined` is coming from.

It's not totally clear from your code, but *probably* you should just pass `cb`:

```
write(name, JSON.stringify(data, null, '\t'), cb)
```

Comment: You are a genious man! I'm trying to understand why?! Still I dont know why?!

Comment: @user3399784 when you mention a function and follow that with `(xxx)`, that means "please call this function right now".  That's just how JavaScript expressions work. `cb(err)` means "call the function referenced by `cb` passing the value of `err`".  It's no different than the surrounding call to the `write()` function, see?